# Background image in eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to put an image as background in eclipse helios's java editor.

Comment: no. the setting that i can change the white background as some custom image

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't have a background image for the editor section of Eclipse.

**To change background colour:**

Open Windows > Preferences > Editors > Text Editors
Browse Appearance color options
Select background color options, uncheck default, change to black
Select background color options, uncheck default, change to colour of choice

Check this : [Color Themes for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96981/color-themes-for-eclipse/4815649#4815649)

Comment: i know about the background color, but in netbeans u can set background image and eclipse doesn't :(. Thanks man

Answer (score -1):

for example: this config set eclipse 4 text editor background image (path "./eclipse-text-editor-background-image.png") from folder "eclipse-kepler-standart/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.2.v20140221-1700/images"
    cat ~/eclipse-kepler-standart/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.2.v20140221-1700/css/e4_basestyle.css

```
.MPart StyledText {
  background-image: url(./eclipse-text-editor-background-image.png);
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.MPartStack {
  swt-unselected-tabs-color: #2D3340 #2D3340 #2D3340 100% 100%;
  swt-outer-keyline-color: #FFFFFF;
    swt-inner-keyline-color: #FFFFFF;
    swt-tab-outline: #B6BCCC;
    swt-shadow-visible: true;
    swt-mru-visible: false;
}

.MPartStack.active {
    swt-inner-keyline-color: #FFFFFF;
    swt-tab-outline: #B6BCCC;
    swt-shadow-visible: true;
}

#PerspectiveSwitcher {
    eclipse-perspective-keyline-color: #AAB0BF #AAB0BF;
}

.MToolBar.Draggable {
    handle-image:  url(./dragHandle.png);
}

.MToolControl.Draggable {
    handle-image:  url(./dragHandle.png);
}

.DragFeedback {
    background-color: #00FF00; 
}

.ModifiedDragFeedback {
    background-color: #A0A000; 
}

CTabItem {
  font: Terminus;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}

CTabItem.busy {
    font-style: italic;
}

CTabItem.highlighted {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```