# How to set an image as the background for Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse

I want to set Eclipse so that I can type my code over a nice looking background picture of my choice. I am ***not*** asking how to make an image the background for a `JFrame` in a program, but how to make a background for the editor in Eclipse. I have looked all over and haven't found anything useful. I read [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063830/background-image-in-eclipse-editor) from 8 years ago, but Eclipse has changed since then. If this is possible please answer my question.

Thank you!

Comment: I have no answer but I'm curious: are you aware of any editor that allows to set a background image? I'm not sure that source code would be really readable over most images.

Comment: Nothing has changed in this area since that previous question.

Comment: @EmmanuelChebbi No, I haven't yet seen an editor that would let you set a background image. I was just wondering about Eclipse.